# MVC Paging based Next And Previous Buttons

Tags: model-view-controller, pagination

I have one table Player.There are player ID Big Integer and Auto Increment.
I want to do paging like Previous and Next Button based on player ID

For Example:
My first Link to view player : /ViewPlayer?playerid=1
Next Page =/ViewPlayer?playerid=2

Comment: That looks like it might work. What happened?

Comment: Yea but my player id is not properly auto incremented.Lets say I have playerid and then there is player id=3 so in this case it will not work.I need just two button "Previous" and "Next" with player id link which is available in database

Comment: Submit the current ID and get the first item in the table where the ID is greater than the current ID

Comment: Ok great I think it will work

Comment: @Stephen Muecke  Thanks a lot its worked for me